# Copy overwriting a file only on RPM update

Tags: puppet

I have following problem with my Puppet installation:

- I would like to copy (overwrite) a file only, if a new version of RPM package was installed.

I have something like this:

```
    package { 'my-rpm':
      ensure => $version,
      source => $rpm_file,
      notify => File[$my_file],
    }

    file { $my_file:
      ensure  => present,
      source  => $my_file_template,
      replace => true,  # Overwrite (default behaviour). Needed in case new RPM was installed.
    }
```

The problem is, that the "file" get executed also, if no new version of RPM was installed. This happens, since I change the $my_file file afterwards using "file_line"

```
    file_line { 'disable_my_service':
      ensure => present,
      path   => $my_file,
      line   => '        <deployment name="My.jar" runtime-name="My.jar" enabled="false">',
      match  => '        <deployment name="My.jar" runtime-name="My.jar">',
    }
```

This change of the content of the $my_file triggers copying fresh version from the template on each and every Puppet run.

I could add "repace => false" to my file copy define, but this would break any further updates...

The long story short: I have the following loop

- Copy file -> change file -> copy file -> ...

How can I break this loop?

**UPDATE:**
Clarification:

- The "file_line" define is executed **optionally**, controlled by a Puppet hiera-property and so the "enabled" part can't be included in the RPM.
- The entire file can't be turned into a template (IMHO). The problem: Puppet module must be able to install different (future) versions of the file.
- The problem remains unsolved for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're getting here is that you're trying to manage `$my_file` using both the *file* and *file_line* resource types and this is going to cause the file to change during the catalog application.
Pick one or the other, manage it as a template or by file line.
I suspect what's happening here during the Puppet run is the `file` resource changes `$my_file` to look like this;

`<deployment name="My.jar" runtime-name="My.jar">`

Because that's what is in the template then, the *file_line* resource changes it to;

`<deployment name="My.jar" runtime-name="My.jar" enabled="false">`

Then on the next run the exact same thing happens, *file* changes `$my_file` to match the template and then *file_line* changes it to modify that line.

I would remove the `notify => File[$my_file],` it's not actually doing anything, you're defining the desired state in code so if that file changes for any reason, manual change or RPM update, Puppet is going to bring that file back into the desired state during the run. You may want to consider;

```
  file { $my_file:
    ensure  => present,
    source  => $my_file_template,
    require => Package['my-rpm'],
  }
```

This ensures the file desired state is enforced after the *package* resource so if the package changes the file the file will be corrected in the same run.
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.4/lang_relationships.html

You may also want to consider;

```
  file { $my_file:
    ensure  => present,
    source  => $my_file_template,
    require => Package['my-rpm'],
    notify  => Service['my-service'],
  }
```

So the service provided by the rpm restarts when the config file is changed.

Comment: Ok, but using only the "file" I can't apply my "enabled" status. It's controlled by the property, so I need to apply it at Puppet-run-time. I could use templates, but then I would have to package the "my_file_template" within the puppet module, but it has to come from the RPM. Any suggestions for that? Thank you!

Comment: So could you just update the source file, changing the `deployment` line to include the `enabled` flag? That way it all happens in one go

Comment: @Jon No, adding this "enabled" flag is optional, controlled by a hiera-property. Actually, I have a dozen of such lines all controlled by different properties. Any other solution idea would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Ah, in which case you should be using EPP templates to control the options - that's the standard Puppet pattern for this kind of thing. Templates are documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template_epp.html#lang_template_epp

Comment: @Jon Thank you for the quick response!! I would love to use templates, but the file is provided by RPM. Puppet module must be able to install different (future) versions of the file... See updated description. Any ideas?

Comment: In which case, just drop the `file` resource and use the `file_line` resources to add your customisations. If you want to base your config on the default RPM one, you don't need to overwrite it with `$my_file_template`. Personally I'd overwrite the entire RPM config file with my own from an EPP template. This is a common pattern with Puppet modules

Answer (score 1):

> Copy overwriting a file only on RPM update

> The problem is, that the "file" get executed also, if no new version of RPM was installed. This happens, since I change the $my_file file afterwards using "file_line"

Yes, `File` resources in a node's catalog are applied on every run.  In fact, it's best to take the view that *every* resource that makes it into in a node's catalog is applied on every run.  Resources' attributes affect what applying them means and / or what it means for them to be in sync, not whether they are applied at all.  In the case of `File`, for example, setting `replace => false` says that as long as the file initially exists, its content is in sync (and therefore should not be modified), whereas `replace => true` says that the file's content is in sync only if it is an exact match to the specified `source` or `content`.

Generally speaking, it does not work well to manage the same or overlapping physical resources via multiple Puppet resources, and that's what you're running into here.  The most idiomatic approach when you run into a problem with that is often to write a custom resource type with which to manage the target object in detail.  But in this case, it looks like you could work around the issue by using an `Exec` to perform the one-time post-update copy:

```
    package { 'my-rpm':
      ensure => $version,
      source => $rpm_file,
    }

    ~> exec { "Start with default ${my_file}":
      command => "cp '${my_file_template}' '${my_file}'",
      # this is important:
      refreshonly => true,
    }

    -> file { $my_file:
      ensure  => 'file',
      replace => false,
      # no source or content
      owner   => 'root', # or whatever
      group   => 'root', # or whatever
      mode    => '0644',
      # ...
    }

    -> file_line { 'disable_my_service':
      ensure => present,
      path   => $my_file,
      # ...
    }
```

You can, of course, use relationship metaparameters instead of the chaining arrows if you prefer or have need.

That approach gives you:

- management of the package via the package manager;
- copying the packaged default file to the target file only when triggered by the package being updated (by Puppet -- you won't get this if the package is updated manually);
- managing properties of the file other than its contents via the `File` resource; and
- managing a specific line of the file's contents via the `File_line` resource.